# Excel crashes when pressing "developer tools" button

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem in Excel:

I wasdevelopping a template  in Excel VBA. I was tearing a sub routine in break mode and tried to stop it to change  the code. When I pressed the stop button, however, Excel froze so I had to kill the process. Although before the crash everything was ok, opening the file would cause excel to freeze and crash again. Obviously the file got corrupt. I used a previous version of the file and decided to redo the changes. At some point the problem happened again. When I finally managed to open the file, everything seemed ok, but pressing the "developer tools" button on the ribbon crashes excel. I desperate. The Template is 90% but making even the slightest change feels like disarming a mine bomb that can blow the template up.

Does anyone know how to bypass the problem?

Comment: What's the "developer tools" button on the Ribbon? You mean the "Visual Basic" button? Are you running any VBE add-ins? This looks more like a problem with Excel or the VBE than a *specific programming issue*.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I would suggest:

1. get another PC with the same version of Excel installed,
2. Install the VBA CodeClener Add-in (http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm),
3. Copy your (prior) spreadsheet over to that PC, open it, open developer tools and run CodeCleaner.
4. Add your changes.

If that works, then reinstall Excel on your first PC.  If not then you will have to take drastic measures:

1. Open the prior version,
2. Make one (or a few) change at a time,
3. After each small set of changes, save a new version of your Excel file, adding a version number to the file name (update the version/file name each time)

If it fails again, go back to the previous version, and the try to figure out which of the small set of changes may have corrupted the file.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment?  Why the down vote?  AFAIK, this is the best advice and answer.  If there's a better answer, please tell us, because I'd like to know it too.

Comment: Sounds like a sound advice. Unfortunately, I didn't have another PC to fall back on to, so I ended up opening an older version of the file I was working on (fortunately, I always save my day's work in a separate file with the version no. added to it when working with MS products). I had to copy the code for each module manually, but once I did it, everything worked.